# unctx:transfrom Unexpected token (65:4) file: /node_modules/nuxt/dist/pages/runtime/router.mjs:65:4 NUXT 3.0

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, aws-sdk-js

When I try to run `npm run generate` it is giving me this error

[image]

It should generate the static nuxtjs site.
Before it was on Nuxt-3-rc and it was building site successfully. As I converted it to Nuxt 3.0 Stable it is giving me this error.

Package.json

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "start": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate ",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare",
    "vite:build": "vite build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "@nuxt/postcss8": "^1.1.3",
    "@nuxtjs/fontawesome": "^1.1.2",
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^5.3.3",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "nuxt": "3.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.19",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@a1ter/nuxt-auth-aws-cognito-scheme": "^0.0.12",
    "@headlessui/vue": "^1.4.2",
    "@mdi/js": "^7.0.96",
    "@nuxtjs/auth-next": "^5.0.0-1637745161.ea53f98",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.4.2",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^5.2.10",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.3.21",
    "chart.js": "^3.9.1",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "pinia": "^2.0.22",
    "readable-stream": "^4.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-polyfills": "^0.2.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, mind sharing your `package.json` + nuxt config file?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
I am using AWS sdk with nuxt 3 which is causing issues.
In Nuxt.config file instead of

```
vite: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        './runtimeConfig': './runtimeConfig.browser'
      }
    },
    // temp-fix for dev, it breaks build for now (see: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/4916)
    define: {
      global: {}
    }
  },
```

Using this would help. Github [Issue](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/4916)

```
vite: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        './runtimeConfig': './runtimeConfig.browser'
      }
    },
    // temp-fix for dev, it breaks build for now (see: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/4916)
    define: {
      'window.global': {}
    }
  },
```